# When transforming XML in XSLT processor, how are entities and modules resolved if they don't exist in XML catalog?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, java-11, dtd

I am running a simple transform against XML containing a DTD. The DTD references .mod and .ent files. I provide an XML catalog for the transform processor. When the catalog contains an entry for the DTD, the DTD is resolved. Apparently none of the entities and modules the DTD depends upon are entries in the catalog, so they come back null. Nevertheless, the transform completes. Likewise, if the DTD in the XML is not matched in the catalog, the transform nevertheless completes.

My test:

```
@Test
    void settingExplicitResolver() throws IOException, TransformerException{
        Source xsl = XslTransform.getXsl("aaas",List.of());

        TransformerFactory factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
        factory.setFeature("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/suppressXsltNamespaceCheck",true);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(writer);
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("xml/plos_test.xml").getFile()
        );

        CatalogFeatures f =
                CatalogFeatures.builder()
                        .with(CatalogFeatures.Feature.FILES, xmlCatalog)
                        .with(CatalogFeatures.Feature.RESOLVE,"ignore")
                        .build();

        Transformer t = factory.newTransformer(xsl);
        t.setURIResolver(CatalogManager.catalogResolver(f, URI.create(xmlCatalog)));
        
        t.transform(xml, streamResult);
```

What is actually happening when the RESOLVE property is set to "ignore"? Are the missing resources downloaded off the web somehow? Also, what is the difference with "continue" and "ignore"?

I also have the catalog tied into Oxygen 17.0, and I see things like this running the same XML through the XSL:

[image: Oxygen output upon transforming same XML]

Comment: As far as I understand it, the method `setURIResolver` is meant to set a URI resolver for resolving any `document()` or `doc()` function calls in the XSLT code. I don't think it is relevant for resolving URIs in DTDs of the input source to the Transformer.

Comment: As for the catalog, the doc https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/catalog/CatalogResolver.html#resolve(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) says "If no mapping is found, returns an empty Source object if the javax.xml.catalog.resolve property is set to ignore;". But as I said in the previous comment, the resolver you set up is about resolving `document()` calls in the XSLT.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I'm seeing that if I set the RESOLVE property to "strict", it attempts to find the .ent and .mod files in the catalog but throws a CatalogException, so it seems that the URI resolver does try to deal in DTDs too. I guess the primary question is "When RESOLVE is 'continue' or 'ignore' and the files aren't resolved through a catalog, is anything downloaded from the web?